# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from External Applications

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've followed the instruction: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external

```
STEP1. $ chmod +x ~/GCP/cloud_sql_proxy

STEP2. $ gcloud auth application-default login

STEP3. $ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306 -credential_file=[PATH_TO_KEY_FILE]
```

I got `2016/12/15 19:55:44 Ready for new connections`

```
STEP4. $ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

But I got the following error in the Terminal;

```
2016/12/15 23:51:20 New connection for "[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"
2016/12/15 23:51:20 Thottling refreshCfg([INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]): it was only
called 23.918136971s ago
2016/12/15 22:08:26 couldn't connect to "[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]": 
Post https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/{PROJECT_ID]/
instances/[INSTANCE_NAME]/createEphemeral?alt=json: private key should be a PEM or
plain PKSC1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial 
communication packet', system error: 0
```

I am stuck here.
Appreciate for all your help.

Comment: Where did the credential file come from? Did you create a service account with Editor role and download the private key? Per https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy#create-service-account.

Comment: @jarmod I got the credential file from STEP#2.

Credentials saved to file [/Users/******/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests
Application Default Credentials.

Comment: @jarmod It works with the service account creation. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. I've added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy#create-service-account) with Editor role and download the private key?

Comment: Yes. I followed your comment and solved it with JSON private key. thanks.